# Graphql-Mesh how to do Authentication with backend services?

Tags: graphql-mesh

I am wondering how do we authenticate graphql-mesh server with backend services that uses oAuth or SAML based authentication. There are examples where I saw use of API-KEY, but how was this API-KEY obtained, do we need to call some method before "yarn mesh" that authenticates and stores API-KEY Somewhere?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I also have the same doubt. I am also looking for some solution where we can integrate Auth process like SSO, jwt and and others